# Mootools class variable scope

Tags: javascript, class, mootools, scope

Take this class:

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    Implements: [Events, Options],
    initialize: function() {

        this.a = 1;

    },

    myMethod: function() {

        var mc = new differentClass({
            events: {
                onClick: function() {

                    console.log(this.a); // undefined (should be 1, 2, 3 etc)

                    this.a ++;


                }
            }
        });    

    }
});
```

How do I keep the value of *this.a*? I am basically trying to draw a line (using canvas) from the last point to the co-ordinates just clicked.

[EDIT]

I dont want to bind `this` as it's bad apparently and it will over-ride the `differentClass` options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

several patterns are available.

decorator via `.bind()`

```
var mc = new differentClass({
    events: {
        click: function() {
             console.log(this.a);
             this.a ++;
        }.bind(this) // binds the scope of the function to the upper scope (myclass)
    }
});
```

keeping a reference.

```
var self = this; // reference parent instance of myClass
var mc = new differentClass({
    events: {
        click: function() {
             console.log(self.a); 
             self.a ++;
        }
    }
});
```

pointing to a myClass method that can deal with it:

```
handleClick: function() {
    this.a++;
},
myMethod: function() {
    var mc = new differentClass({
        events: {
            click: this.handleClick.bind(this)
        }
    });    
}
```

the 2-nd one - by storing a reference is preferred due to the smaller footprint and universal support whereas `.bind` is not available in every browser and needs to be shimmed as well as the extra time to curry the function on execution.

`self` is what you will find in mootools-core itself when possible.

if performance is not at risk, method 3 can probably offer the best readability and code structure. the arguments to the method will remain what the click handler passes, i.e. `event` and `event.target` will be the handler.

in pattern #2 with `self`, `this` will point to the click handler within the anonymous function (or to the other class, for example), which may be useful as well - rebinding context can be a pain in the neck

Comment: Ahhhhh! I was always putting the `var _self = this` in the initialize method.

Comment: ahhh i remember once there were a heated debate over this on Mootools IRC.  Good old days =)

Comment: @kjy112 still feeling mootools withdrawal symptoms? :D

Answer (score 2):

You can refer proper context like this:

```
...
myMethod: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var mc = new differentClass({
        events: {
            onClick: function() {
                console.log(_this.a);
                _this.a ++;
            }
        }
    });    
}
...
```